# If $a_n\ge0$ and $\sum a_n$ converges then $\sum\sqrt{a_na_{n-1}}$ converges, what about the converse?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

1. Suppose the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n}$ is convergent ($a_n \geq0$), Is it true that  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sqrt{a_na_{n-1}}$ is convergent ?
2. Is the converse true?

My attempt:

The first part I was able to do using AM-GM inequality and comparison test for series.

But I am not able to prove or generate a counter example for the second part.

Comment: Another example: fix $b_n$ to be any divergent series you like and define $a_{2n} = b_n$ and $a_{2n+1} = 0$. Then $a_na_{n-1} = 0$ so $\sum \sqrt{a_na_{n-1}} = 0$ is convergent but $\sum a_n = \sum b_n$ is divergent.

Comment: The title does a poor job at reflecting the question the OP asked.

Comment: Maybe if $a_n$ is decreasing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it is not true. Define $a_n = n^2$ for $n$ even and $a_n = n^{-100}$ for $n$ odd. Then clearly $\sum a_n$ is divergent, but each term

$$\sqrt{a_n a_{n - 1}} \sim n^{-49}$$

gives a convergent series.

Answer (score 1):

The converse is not ture. For example consider the following sequense $\{a_n\}$.
$$a_n =
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{1}{2^nn}   & \text{if $n$ is even} \\[2ex]
n & \text{if $n$ is odd .}
\end{cases}$$

Then $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\sqrt{a_na_{n-1}}$ is convergent. But $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n}$ is divergent.